# $r \mathbb{Z}_n$ is projective as $\mathbb{Z}_n$-module

Tags: modules, exact-sequence, projective-module

Let $n=rs$ be a natural bigger than $1$, show that $r \mathbb{Z}_n$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}_n$-module.

Well, when $r$ and $s$ are coprimes we have that $\mathbb{Z}_n \simeq r \mathbb{Z}_n \oplus s\mathbb{Z}_n $. Since $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is projective over itself we have that $r\mathbb{Z}_n$ projective.

How it works when $r$ and $s$ are not coprimes??

Answer (score 1):

It's not true in general.  If $r=s=2$, $n=4$, then $2\mathbb{Z}_4$ is not projective as a $\mathbb{Z}_4$-module.  To see this, note $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is local and hence projective modules are free, but $2\mathbb{Z}_4$ is not free.

Comment: I guess $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not a local ring over $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Comment: I don't know what it means for a ring to be local over another ring.  The ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is local iff $n$ is a prime power.  That was just a way to explain why $2\mathbb{Z}_4$ is not projective, but it's really not needed.  You can show $r\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not projective whenever $r,s$ are not coprime.